# is Jcron for Java scheduling?

Tags: joomla, scheduler

I have been searching through entire Internet for sometime and I am not able to understand whether Jcron is a API for Java scheduling or is it specific only to Joomla CMS ? 
If it can be used with Java can someone share links of some Example.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

From the [Jcron web page](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/jcron_scheduler/):

> JCron Scheduler is a Joomla component for Cron Jobs Management and Scheduling! It's purpose is to simulate cron jobs through Joomla front end interface at preset periods of time for users who either don't have access to the server crontab or don't want to use it for any purpose!

It is clearly something that belongs to Joomla world, and has nothing to do with Java. If you are looking for cron like scheduling in Java you should check [cron4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/).